# Div height issues , Div height does not cover whole body

Tags: html, css

I have slider panel ,what i am doing , when my slider open then it's cover all height, but not able to this , when i am going with body overlay hidden then ,height is fixed and full content is not showing,http://polestarllp.com/polestarnew/our-core-values/

```
body{
      background-color:#FFF;
      height:100%;
     width:100%;
     margin:0;
      color:#ccc;
      font-size:3em;
      line-height:100px;
      text-align:center;
     overflow:hidden;
    }
    .slidernav{
      background:#000;
      position:absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height:100%;
      top: 0;
      right:-100%;
      z-index:9999999999999999999999;
      overflow:hidden;
    }
```

html

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="slidernav"><div>
</html>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `overflow:hidden;` use `overflow-x:hidden;`

Answer (score 1):

Some Time Create problem with use `overflow: hidden`, So Below is the best solution

```css
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }

* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="slidernav clearfix">
  
<div>

</body>
</html>
```